# Vim default key binding

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

I want my mapleader to be <kbd>;</kbd> and keep his Vim functionality, therefore remap the default <kbd>;</kbd> Vim function to another key, let's say <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>

I'm new to Vim and it seems like a simple question but I can't find exactly what I what. If you think it's a bad idea, feel free to criticize.

I've already included this line in my .vimrc:

```
let mapleader = ";"
```

Comment: Read `help map` to learn about mapping keys. Youll likely want `nnoremap` here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## TL;DR

Use `noremap` (`nnoremap` to make sure make it work only in normal mode)

```
let mapleader=";"
nnoremap '. ;
```

#### Better leader

IMO, you should remap `;` to `:` (if you're on QWERTY). Most people remap their leader to `,` also. I think you should do the same (I did and I'm very happy with it). Here's how you do it (just adapt it to your needs).

### `map` vs `noremap`

`map` allows you to map certain keystrokes to other ones. For example:

```
map ; :
```

What this does is as soon as you press `;`, it'll do exactly what it would've done if you pressed `:`.

To restrict this shortcut to work only in normal mode, just use `nmap`:

```
nmap ; :
```

BTW, do you know what it would have done if you used `map` and pressed `;` in insert mode? It would have inserted a `:`!

The problem with `map` (and `nmap`, `imap`, all the family) is that it uses user defined shortcut. For example

```
imap a b
imap b c
```

So, when you press `a`, it'll in fact "press" `b`, and then "press" `c` because of the second `imap` (in insert mode of cours). So, when you press `a`, it'll insert a `c`.

And that's no good at all. It might sounds good, but it isn't reliable, since everything can be remap without you knowing.

So, to counter that, you got `noremap` (and `nnoremap`, `inoremap`, all the family again). These ones only use vim's **default keybindings**. It doesn't take into account the other mapping. **That's the ones you want to use** unless you *want* to use a plugin's shortcut, or one of yours.

So, with the previous example, if we would have used `inoremap`, and press `a`, we would've got `b`.

So, we can now interchange `:` and `;`:

```
nnoremap ; :
nnoremap : ;
```

If you use `nmap`, it'll loop forever (`;` would press `:`, which would press `;`, which would...)

### Visual mode

You'll probably want this remap in visual mode too:

```
nnoremap : ;
nnoremap ; :
vnoremap ; :
vnoremap : ;
```

If you want to learn vim, I strongly recommend you read [Learn VimScript the hard way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/).

If you want to see the different options about anything in vim, the `help`'s great. In this case `:help map`.

#### Extra tip

```
:tab help map
```

Opens the help page in a new tab (`gt` and `gT` to navigate tabs)